# SharePoint Online document Library

Tags: document-library, file, sync

I want to remove the files from my Computer after that automatically sync to the SharePoint online Document library. any solution?

Comment: You can stop syncing that folder using the Notification Icon available in task bar. Then delete the files from computer.

Comment: Can't I automate this process of removing from the system?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to MAP the SharePoint Library folder to my local computer, so when I place the file there, it should only on SharePoint folder not on my computer, I'm using office 365 and in that I can't map the folder I can only Sync the folder.

Comment: Try this to map http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_made_easy/archive/2013/03/20/map-network-drive-webdav-with-sharepoint-online-o365.aspx

Comment: Cool. I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Mapping a Drive to SharePoint Online it fails with below error.

The Mapped Network Drive could not be created because the following error has occurred.
'Access Denied'. Before opening files in this location, you must first add the web site to your trusted sites list, browse to the web site and select the option to login Automatically.

**Resolution**

1. Open IE -> Go to ‘Internet Options’
2. Select ‘Security’ tab -> Select ‘Internet’ Zone.
3. UnCheck the box for ‘Enable Protected Mode’

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_made_easy/archive/2013/03/20/map-network-drive-webdav-with-sharepoint-online-o365.aspx